# Configure OpenVPN server for mobile devices only, possible?

Tags: openvpn

does anyone can let me know please if we can set an openvpn server to accept only mobile devices ? The request of the customer is to configure an openvpn server only for mobile devices (android, iOS).
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the OpenVPN client or protocol that detects the OS or hardware of the device being used to connect.

I suspect you are already only issuing your configuration and certs to these mobile devices and you don't want users exporting or re-using the config/credentials on other systems.  Unfortunately I really doubt there is any method that would permit this.

I suspect you may need to resolve your 'underlying' problem differently.  Perhaps by adjusting which routes you push, and how the OpenVPN client is configured to **lock down the VPN network so that it is only useful for accessing the network resources that would of interest to your mobile devices users.**

Comment: seems that using --push-peer-info is a way to do it